# MySQL performance issue with multiple JOIN

Tags: mysql, sql, performance, join

I'm developing a professional web based service capable to monitor electrical energy consumption or energy production (i.e. from Photovoltaic or Wind power sources). The project uses a proprietary electronic (developed by me) that collects the electrical parameters such as voltage, current and phase angle.

- The remote device sends those parameters to a Apache web server script that push the raw data into a MySQL database hosted on a separate server.
- Each remote device has its own DEVICE_ID.
- Data are sent every 30 seconds, hence in one day we have 2880 rows for each device.

Apache server doesn't show any performance issue while despite the big calculation power of the MySQL server I'm unable to get the query executed in less than 60 seconds. I've used all the tools (keys and indexes) and designed the query properly (I hope) but I'm unable to understand what's wrong.

My experience in DB design comes from Oracle and SQL Server mostly, I have very limited experience (as professional) on MySQL.

The server hardware: 2x Xeon CPU 64bits + 4GB RAM running on Windows Server 2008, yes MySQL is installed on Windows2008 as it's a platform that I know very well.

The database is very simple:

Table1: DATA_RAW is made of several fields hosting the electrical parameters, plus the SRV_TIMESTAMP field containing the TIMESTAMP of the data raw, the DEVICE_ID field containing the remote device ID.

All the remote devices push their data into this table every 30 seconds. The Primary Key is a clustered one: DEVICE_ID+SRV_TIMESTAMP as with those fields it's impossible to have duplicated rows coming from the same device.

The system receives also meteorological data such as temperature, pressure, humidity, clouds, and so on. They are sent every hour. Those data are pushed into another table named  WEATHER_DATA, again the Primary Key is a clustered one: DEVICE_ID+SRV_TIMESTAMP. The only difference is that we have just 24 rows per device every day here.

There is a third table named SUN_DATA that contains information about sun irradiance for each device. This is used to compute the PV field efficiency. The table hosting those data is named SUN_DATA and contains various field, again the Primary Key is a clustered one: DEVICE_ID+SRV_TIMESTAMP.

It's important to note that the SRV_TIMESTAMP is synchronized among all devices so any data set will share the same timeslot (one of the 2880 timeslots available every day).

Here a sample of the data coming from the DATA_RAW table:

```
SRV_TIMESTAMP       | DEVICE_ID | VOLTAGE | CURRENT | PHASE
-----------------------------------------------------------
2014-08-21 22:23:30 | 0AF500100 |     243 |     5.4 |  0.01
2014-08-21 22:23:30 | 0AF456102 |     240 |     3.4 |  0.15
2014-08-21 22:23:30 | 0BFDE0010 |     239 |     2.4 |  0.65
2014-08-21 22:23:00 | 0AF500100 |     241 |     5.2 |  0.37
2014-08-21 22:23:00 | 0AF456102 |     239 |     3.4 |  0.12
2014-08-21 22:23:00 | 0BFDE0010 |     238 |     2.5 |  0.64
2014-08-21 22:22:30 | 0AF500100 |     240 |     5.4 |  0.02
2014-08-21 22:22:30 | 0AF456102 |     236 |     3.2 |  0.16
2014-08-21 22:22:30 | 0BFDE0010 |     239 |     2.0 |  0.67
```

Here a sample of the data coming from the DATA_SUN table:

```
SRV_TIMESTAMP       | DEVICE_ID | SUNPOWER| SUNAZIMUTH
------------------------------------------------------
2014-08-21 22:23:30 | 0AF500100 |  845674 |      175.1
2014-08-21 22:23:30 | 0AF456102 |  866467 |      175.2
2014-08-21 22:23:30 | 0BFDE0010 |  867686 |      175.4
2014-08-21 22:23:00 | 0AF500100 |  867685 |      175.6
2014-08-21 22:23:00 | 0AF456102 |  867876 |      175.9
2014-08-21 22:23:00 | 0BFDE0010 |  867855 |      176.0
2014-08-21 22:22:30 | 0AF500100 |  867879 |      176.2
2014-08-21 22:22:30 | 0AF456102 |  856578 |      176.4
2014-08-21 22:22:30 | 0BFDE0010 |  876789 |      176.4
```

Here a sample of the data coming from the DATA_WEATHER table:

```
SRV_TIMESTAMP       | DEVICE_ID | CLOUDS | TEMPERATURE
------------------------------------------------------
2014-08-21 22:00:00 | 0AF500100 |     30 |      36.1
2014-08-21 22:00:00 | 0AF456102 |     35 |      26.2
2014-08-21 22:00:00 | 0BFDE0010 |     34 |      35.4
2014-08-21 21:00:00 | 0AF500100 |     70 |      36.6
2014-08-21 21:00:00 | 0AF456102 |     10 |      26.9
2014-08-21 21:00:00 | 0BFDE0010 |     20 |      35.0
2014-08-21 20:00:00 | 0AF500100 |     30 |      32.2
2014-08-21 20:00:00 | 0AF456102 |     20 |      23.4
2014-08-21 20:00:00 | 0BFDE0010 |     65 |      34.4
```

Note that for the weather only, data are pushed every hour while for the other tables data are pushed every 30 seconds.
Here the detailed table structure for the DATA_RAW table (the other 2 tables are similar, just name of fields are different):

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `data_raw` (
  `SRV_TIMESTAMP` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  `DEVICE_ID` char(5) NOT NULL,
  `VOLTAGE` decimal(2,0) NOT NULL,
  `CURRENT` decimal(2,0) NOT NULL,
  `PHASE` decimal(3,0) NOT NULL
)
ENGINE=InnoDB
DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
COMMENT='RAW DATA COMING FROM DEVICE IN A SINGLE TIMESLOT';

ALTER TABLE `data_raw`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`DEVICE_ID`,`SRV_TIMESTAMP`) COMMENT 'PRIMARY KEY',
  ADD KEY `IDX_DEVICE_ID` (`DEVICE_ID`);
```

Now the problem:

I need to compute various data and in order to do that I join the electrical data with weather data and with sun data as follows:

```
SELECT
  D.VOLTAGE,
  D.CURRENT,
  S.SUNPOWER1,
  S.SUNAZIMUTH,
  W.CLOUDS,
  W.TEMPERATURE  
FROM
  DATA_RAW AS D 
  JOIN SUN_DATA AS S ON
    S.SRV_TIMESTAMP=D.SRV_TIMESTAMP
    AND S.DEVICE_ID=D.DEVICE_ID 
  LEFT JOIN WEATHER_DATA AS W ON
    HOUR(W.SRV_TIMESTAMP)=HOUR(D.SRV_TIMESTAMP)
    AND MONTH(W.SRV_TIMESTAMP)=MONTH(D.SRV_TIMESTAMP)
    AND YEAR(W.SRV_TIMESTAMP)=YEAR(D.SRV_TIMESTAMP)
    AND S.DEVICE_ID=D.DEVICE_ID
ORDER BY D.SRV_TIMESTAMP DESC
```

This query takes more than 60 seconds with just 40.000 rows in DATA_RAW and SUN_DATA and 150 rows in WEATHER_DATA.

Changing the field order into the join doesn't give any benefit.
Where's the error?

Comment: It's hard to know exactly what's wrong without knowing your tables and indexes, so you might want to make your question more concise and provide that information, but one obvious problem is your usage of functions in filtering clauses. Even if you have indexes, when you use something like `HOUR(W.SRV_TIMESTAMP)`, you prevent any indexes from being used and you'll have a full table scan with the function being applied to every row.

Comment: 1. Your question is hard to read. Please split it into multiple paragraphs. 2. You have described the tables but have not specified what indexes you have. 3. If possible, provide a database dump with real looking data (Does not need to be actual data but something that is similar)

Comment: I've followed @some suggestions, hope that now the question is easier to read.

Comment: Hi @Pedro Werneck, many thanks for your reply. Even remoiving the HOUR() function (that I was forced to use as the weather data are pushed only every hour not every 30 seconds as in the other table) the situation remains critical. The same database and the same query takes 0.03 seconds on SQL Server 2005 Express (Microsoft).

Comment: Your tables clearly don't have any indexes. You might want to denormalize the timestamp components in separated indexed columns. I don't doubt the same works better in SQL Server, but in MySQL, querying with functions on the filtering clauses is guaranteed to kill your query performance.

Comment: @Pedro Werneck, do you mean I have to split the SRV_TIMESTAMP into YEAR,MONTH,DAY,HOUR,MINUTE,SECONDS and create a clustered primary key with those fields plus the DEVICE_ID?

Comment: Yes to split the timestamp into the fields you need, but you need to do some research into MySQL indexing. That's a little beyond the scope here.

Comment: In that case I would prefer to add a unique auto-increment ID for each table acting as a PK. Then I would create another table containing the SRV-TIMESTAMP, DEVICE_ID and PK. Doing that there will be no mess with  keys during JOINS. Obviously I have to clone wasteful rows into DATA_WEATHER table in order to avoid to use the HOUR(), in that case almost 99% of the DATA_WEATHER table will contain duplicated data sets but the PK will be unique. I have just experimented that and now the query execution time is 1,5sec, still high but better than 60 secs,but no chances to get close to SQLServer speed

Comment: I created a database with the schema you specified above, added a unique index on the time and device id on DATA_SUN and DATA_WEATHER, added a column with the timestamp of the latest report on DATA_RAW, filled the database with fake data, and got the result in less than 0.2 seconds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did some tests and got the query down to less than 0.2 seconds on my hardware (Intel Xeon CPU E3-1220 (4 cores), 16GB, running Linux and MariaDb (the drop-in replacement of mysql))

First I created the tables as below. Please note that I increased the number of chars in device_id and changed the precision and scale of the decimal type to match the sample data that you provided. I also added a field `weatherts` to data_raw, that holds the timestamp of the latest weather report for the device. (You could query for the latest weather report timestamp before you insert the raw data, and you could also update the timestamp of previous records when you get a weather report).

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `data_raw` (
  `SRV_TIMESTAMP` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  `DEVICE_ID` char(8) NOT NULL,
  `VOLTAGE` decimal(3,0) NOT NULL,
  `CURRENT` decimal(2,1) NOT NULL,
  `PHASE` decimal(3,2) NOT NULL,
  `weatherts` timestamp
)
ENGINE=InnoDB
DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
COMMENT='RAW DATA COMING FROM DEVICE IN A SINGLE TIMESLOT';

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `data_sun` (
  `SRV_TIMESTAMP` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  `DEVICE_ID` char(8) NOT NULL,
  `SUNPOWER` decimal(10,0) NOT NULL,
  `SUNAZIMUTH` decimal(4,1) NOT NULL
)
ENGINE=InnoDB
DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
COMMENT='SUN DATA';


CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `data_weather` (
  `SRV_TIMESTAMP` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  `DEVICE_ID` char(8) NOT NULL,
  `CLOUDS` decimal(2,0) NOT NULL,
  `TEMPERATURE` decimal(3,1) NOT NULL
)
ENGINE=InnoDB
DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
COMMENT='WEATHER DATA';
```

I created a script that created faked data for 16 units, every 30 seconds to data_raw and data_sun, and every hour for data_weather, resulting in 46080 rows of data each for data_raw and data_sun and 384 rows in data_weather.

Querying the *data_raw* with `SELECT * FROM data_raw` takes about 0.10 seconds.

I tried the first part of the query, where I join the data_raw and data_sun. Without an index it takes forever, so I create an index on data_sun:

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX SUN_PKEY ON data_sun (SRV_TIMESTAMP, DEVICE_ID);
```

Now the query below takes about 0.10 seconds too.

```
SELECT
  D.SRV_TIMESTAMP, D.DEVICE_ID, D.VOLTAGE, D.CURRENT, D.PHASE,
  S.SUNPOWER, S.SUNAZIMUTH
FROM data_raw AS D
  LEFT JOIN data_sun AS S ON
    (S.SRV_TIMESTAMP=D.SRV_TIMESTAMP AND S.DEVICE_ID=D.DEVICE_ID);
```

To be able to do the full query I also add an index on data_weather:

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX WEATHER_PKEY ON data_weather (SRV_TIMESTAMP, DEVICE_ID);
```

Now it is time to test the query:

```
SELECT
  D.SRV_TIMESTAMP, D.DEVICE_ID, D.VOLTAGE, D.CURRENT, D.PHASE,
  S.SUNPOWER, S.SUNAZIMUTH,
  W.CLOUDS, W.TEMPERATURE
FROM data_raw AS D
  LEFT JOIN data_sun AS S ON
    (S.SRV_TIMESTAMP=D.SRV_TIMESTAMP AND S.DEVICE_ID=D.DEVICE_ID)
  LEFT JOIN data_weather AS W ON
    (D.WEATHERTS = W.SRV_TIMESTAMP AND W.DEVICE_ID=D.DEVICE_ID)
ORDER BY D.SRV_TIMESTAMP, D.DEVICE_ID;
```

Now I get 46080 rows in 0.13 sec. Since it took about 0.10 seconds just to read the data_raw table, I think it is pretty good.

Comment: Awesome, thank you @some!
You gave me several good hints: placing a FK to link the weather data and avoid to use functions on the index is the best idea, I don't realize why I didn't that before. Just with that the speed rised up a lot. I'm changing the structure of both tables and related queries and testing the performances. It looks like the root of the problem was the HOUR() function misplaced on a index, this caused MySQL not to use the index and scan the whole table.
Anyway first class support! Thank You!

Comment: @PowerEngineering Nice that it worked out for you :) Please accept this answer.

Comment: I'm a newbie in StackExchange, my reputation is just 6, unable to accept the answer yet. But as soon as my scoe will rise up I will.

Comment: @PowerEngineering I'm thought everyone could accept an answer on their own question... but you needed 15 to up-vote.

Comment: as soon as I gained the score to vote and accept your answer, I did it. ;-) thanks again!

Comment: @PowerEngineering Thank you! Now I only have 600 points left before I become a "Trusted user"!Yeah!